# Set different santum token expiration base on user role using laravel

Tags: laravel, sanctum

I know I can set sanctum token expiration time in config/sanctum.php but this expiration seems to be global. How can I set a different expiration time base on their role. e.g super admin token should expire after 30 minutes while admin should expire after 15 minute.

Answer (score 0):

While authenticating a user, You can dynamically set 'expiration' key of sanctum configuration based on your user type.

```
config(['sanctum.expiration' => 525600]);
```

Comment: Please where do I use this code in my laravel application